# jQuery .submit() success or failure trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using `.submit()` to submit my form over ajax periodically, but I want the user to see that the form is being saved with a spinning wheel and then 'Saved!' upon success. Is there a `success` trigger for `.submit()` in jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a manual `$.post()` request instead of a `.submit()`. The `$.post()` has a success callback.

You'll have to fill in the details of the `$.post()` (the target URL) and `.serialize()` your form's elements.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        var status = '<img class="loading" src="loading_detail.gif" alt="Loading..." />';
        $("#ajax").after(status);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.type == 'success') {
                    $('#msg').css("color","green").html(json.message);
                } else if(json.type == 'warning'){
                    $('#msg').css("color","yellow").html(json.message);
                } else if(json.type == 'error'){
                    $('#msg').css("color","red").html(json.message);
                }
                $('.loading').remove();
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<form id="form" method="post" action="action.php" >
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><span id="ajax"></span>
</form>
```

action.php :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$val = $_POST['email'];
switch ($val) {
    case 'email@site.com':
        $return = array('type'=>'success', 'message'=>'This is success message!'); break;
    case 'email':
        $return = array('type'=>'warning', 'message'=>'This is warning message!'); break;
    default:
        $return = array('type'=>'error', 'message'=>'This is error message!');
}
echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

**Note:**
If you are submitting the form programmatically you need to call `$('#form').submit()` once again but this time without arguments so that you trigger the submit event.

Comment: the `something` portion of your answer seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

To show a spinning wheel while submitting a page, try to get a animated GIF (there are much free loading circles). This GIF implement in your page with:

```
class="myloadingcircle" style="display:none"
```

and then use jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) { $(".myloadingcircle").show(); });
```

Comment: This does not work if paired with form validation. The spinning wheel will be shone even if the form is invalid.